# Remove revert after dropping helper out of sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

**Edit: Barebones jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/37cwgxd1/

I'm having some difficulty with the revert setting in Sortable.

I have Sortable delete the ui.item when it's dropped out of the Sortable list. Works great, except that on mouseStop, the helper reverts back to it's original position and then fires the beforeStop function that removes the ui.item.

The desired effect would be the helper does not revert after mouseStop when outside of the Sortable list. Better yet, it'd be great if the helper scaled to 0 and then was cleared.

Here's my script that calls Sortable:

```
$(function() {
$( "#pl #da-thumbs" ).sortable({cursor: "move"}, {delay: 150}, {appendTo: 'body'}, {   revert: '100'}, {scroll: false}, {
receive: function(event, ui)
{
    sortableIn = 1;
    $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({"opacity":"1.0" , "transform":"scale(1.0)"});
},
over: function(event, ui)
{
    sortableIn = 1;
    $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({"opacity":"1.0" , "transform":"scale(1.0)"});
},
out: function(event, ui)
{
    sortableIn = 0;
    $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({"opacity":"0.3" , "transform":"scale(0.8)"});
},
beforeStop: function(event, ui)
{
    if (sortableIn == 0)
    {
        ui.item.remove();
    }
}
});
```

Here's the applicable section of sortable.js source that applies to the revert and _mouseStop:

```
_mouseStop: function(event) {

    //If we are using droppables, inform the manager about the drop
    var that = this,
        dropped = false;
    if ($.ui.ddmanager && !this.options.dropBehaviour) {
        dropped = $.ui.ddmanager.drop(this, event);
    }

    //if a drop comes from outside (a sortable)
    if (this.dropped) {
        dropped = this.dropped;
        this.dropped = false;
    }

    if ((this.options.revert === "invalid" && !dropped) || (this.options.revert === "valid" && dropped) || this.options.revert === true || ($.isFunction(this.options.revert) && this.options.revert.call(this.element, dropped))) {
        $(this.helper).animate(this.originalPosition, parseInt(this.options.revertDuration, 10), function() {
            if (that._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
                that._clear();
            }
        });
    } else {
        if (this._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
            this._clear();
        }
    }

    return false;
},
```

If I need to modify sortbale.js to get this to work, that's fine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem. Sets revert to false when helper is positioned out. Sets revert back to 100 when it's over. Also on drop, I move the ui.item to the position of the helper (with absolute positioning) and scaled it down to 0 for a nice disappearing effect.

Check out the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37cwgxd1/5/

```
var sort = $(function () {
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cursor: "move"
}, {
    tolerance: "pointer"
}, {
    delay: 150
}, {
    appendTo: 'body'
}, {
    revert: '100'
}, {
    scroll: false
}, {
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        sortableIn = 1;
        $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({
            "opacity": "1.0",
            "transform": "scale(1.0)"
        });
    },
    over: function (event, ui) {
        sortableIn = 1;
        $("#sortable").sortable({ revert: '100' });
        $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({
            "opacity": "1.0",
            "transform": "scale(1.0)"
        });
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        sortableIn = 0;
        $("#sortable").sortable({ revert: false });
        $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({
            "opacity": "0.3",
            "transform": "scale(0.8)"
        });
    },
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        var pos = ui.position,
            top = pos.top,
            left = pos.left,
            item = ui.item,
            width = item.css("width"),
            height = item.css("height");

        if (sortableIn == 0) {

            ui.item.attr("style", ui.item.attr("style") + " " +
                  "position: absolute; " + 
                  "top: " + top + "px; " +
                  "height: " + height + "px; " +
                  "width: " + width + "; " +
                  "left: " + left + "px; ");
            ui.item.css({
            "transform": "scale(0.0)"
        }).animate({
                opacity: "0.0"
            }, '300', function () {
                ui.item.remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
});

$(window).load(sort);
```